# Could dynamic linking hurt inlining thus performance in GHC?

Tags: haskell, inline, ghc, dynamic-linking

It's no secret that inlining is what's enabling a lot of the sophisticated optimizations GHC can carry out. If I link a library dynamically (and get an actual dll/so file out of it), could GHC still inline where it would have, as if the link was static, and depend on the dll for the rest? or do I actually get less optimizations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a function is marked as either `{-# INLINE #-}` or `{-# INLINEABLE #-}`—or if GHC considers it Cheap Enough™—the entire unmangled RHS is included in the interface `.hi` file alongside the compiled `.o` object. As far as I'm aware.

So no, I'm pretty sure it wouldn't hurt inlining. Dynamic linking would affect code locality though, but that's microöptimisation compared to the inlining aspect you're concerned about.

Caveat: I have not actually benchmarked anything.

Comment: Do you have anything to back that up? I mean, I'm aware of interface files but I don't know whether GHC will use them for a shared library. And how would it be? do I supply the shared library path + path for the interface files to the compilation arguments for the executable? I haven't been able to find much information about this whole thing; it's very vague for me at the moment. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: That was off the top of my head, but you can read about it on the [GHC wiki](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/IfaceFiles). GHC wouldn't be able to typecheck anything (and more besides) _without_ the interface files.

You could read up on how to [build shared objects](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-shared-libs.html), but I'd just let `cabal` [deal with it](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html). (Search for `shared`.)

You've not mentioned why you wanted to use shared libs. So why?

Comment: Oh! your typecheck remark made a lot of sense suddenly for all of it; very clever of you. Then I suppose I can really trust it would inline, given that it must have the information it needs to do so. I don't want to use shared libs for anything specific at the moment, I just didn't want to rule them out from my arsenal for when performance matters (e.g. even a simple loop repeating a small function from a shared library could severely bite me if inlining wasn't there). Thank you very much!

Comment: Some libraries (I'm thinking of `vector` in particular) depend heavily on inlining and GHC rewrite `RULES` (also in the `.hi`) to achieve its claimed fusion/deforestation/performance characteristics. I'd consider it a bug in GHC's implementation of shared libraries had it a significant negative impact.